# Swift Codable:Nested Dictionary not being read

Tags: swift, codable

I am getting some json like so (this is pseudo, not all keys are here):

```
{
    "absolute_magnitude_h" = "23.4";
    ...
    "close_approach_data" = (
                {
            "close_approach_date" = "1994-09-03";
            "epoch_date_close_approach" = 778575600000;
            "orbiting_body" = Earth;
}
```

I have an object with this struct:

```
struct NEOObj:Codable {

    var absoluteMagnitudeH:Float
    var designation:String
    var isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid:Bool
    var isSentryObject:Bool
    var name:String
    var nasaJPLURL:String
    var neoReferenceID:String
    var closeApproachData:[NEOCloseApproachData] = [NEOCloseApproachData]()

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case absoluteMagnitudeH = "absolute_magnitude_h"
        case designation = "designation"
        case isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid = "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid"
        case isSentryObject = "is_sentry_object"
        case name = "name"
        case nasaJPLURL = "nasa_jpl_url"
        case neoReferenceID = "neo_reference_id"
    }

enum CloseApproachCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case closeApproachDate = "close_approach_date"
        case epochDateCloseApproach = "epoch_date_close_approach"
        case orbitingBody = "orbiting_body"
    }

struct NEOCloseApproachData:Codable {

    var closeApproachDate:Date
    var epochDateCloseApproach:Date
    var orbitingBody:String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case closeApproachDate = "close_approach_date"
        case epochDateCloseApproach = "epoch_date_close_approach"
        case orbitingBody = "orbiting_body"
    }
}
```

and in my file I have this code:

```
if let arrNEOs = dictJSON["near_earth_objects"] as? Array<Any> {

    for thisNEODict in arrNEOs {

     do {
         let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: thisNEODict, options: .prettyPrinted)
         let thisNEOObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(NEOObj.self, from: jsonData)
         print(thisNEOObj!.closeApproachData)
     } catch {

     }
    }

   }
```

But closeApproachData never gets populated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand, your `thisNEOObj` variable is non-nil, but rather the `closeApproachDate` property is nil, am I correct?

Comment: thisNEOObj has the expected values, closeApproachData is always [ ]

Comment: What is `CloseApproachCodingKeys`? And the `close_approach_data` CodingKey is missing therefore it doesn't get decoded.

Comment: That's a typo, I fixed the question.

Comment: @vadian I think I am still confused on how to format this. It still returning [ ] for thisNeoObj.closeApproachData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things that would need to be changed for it to work.

---

`closeApproachData` should probably be of type `[NEOCloseApproachData]`. You haven't included `CloseApproachCodingKeys` in your code but it probably isn't right.

---

`NEOObj.CodingKeys` needs to have a case for `closeApproachData` which would look like

```
case closeApproachData = "close_approach_data"
```

---

`NEOCloseApproachData` needs a custom decoder to work with the dates for `closeApproachDate` and `epochDateCloseApproach`. Since the JSON has different formats for each (String and Int respectively), you can't use on the `JSONDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy` since it will apply to all dates.

Comment: Thanks, the first comment about the type was just me being careless, the second comment set me straight. It's working now. Well, I omitted the dates for now, hadn't even looked at them yet since nothing else was working. : )

Answer (score 1):

The reason why after decoding you get `closeApproachData` property empty is the lack of the regarding key for that property into your **CodingKeys** enum.

Regarding to the Apple doc, it tells next:

> Omit properties from the CodingKeys enumeration if they won't be
>   present when decoding instances, or if certain properties shouldn't be
>   included in an encoded representation.

That means that generated implementation of `decode` method for your NEOObj class omit decoding implementation for the `closeApproachData` property.

Here's a link at the Apple documentation about [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). You can find more details at the "Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys" paragraph.

Also your custom class *NEOCloseApproachData* should be conformed to the Coding protocol.